# Progress Bar display doesn't match values

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 64bits, trying to make a simple program to manage the copy of some files, like TeraCopy.

I'm facing this problem :
I've got a progress bar, showing the main progression(number of copied files / total numer of files), and the display doesn't match the values...

Here is a video of the behaviour : https://vid.me/tDc1

Here is the code :

```
_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Maximum = FileList.Length;
_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Value = 0;

int fileCounter = 1;
foreach (string File in FileList)
{
    Program.move(File, _destinationFolder.SelectedPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File), (fileCounter++).ToString() + " / " + FileList.Length.ToString());
    Trace.write(File);
    ++_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Value;

    //_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Update();
    //_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Refresh();
    _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Invalidate();
}
```

By the way, I tried using this too :

_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Step = 1;

(...)

_totalProcessFileProgressBar.PerformStep();

The result is identical.

In debug mode, I can see the value of the progress bar is 4 for example, the maximum is 8 and the bar is only displaying maybe 30% of progress.

Ok, so I did used `totalProcessFileProgressBar.Maximum = FileList.Length - 1`, and changed my `Program.move()` method to `async`, the behaviour is exaclty the same.

Here is some more code :

Program.move() :

```
public async static Task<int> move(String inFileName, String outFileName, string text, bool copy = false)
{
    FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(inFileName);
    if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    FileStream streamIn = null;

    try
    {
        streamIn = new FileStream(inFileName, FileMode.Open);
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
    {
        Trace.write("[IOException]" + inFileName + " : " + ex.Message);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        Trace.write("[UnauthorizedAccessException]" + inFileName + " : " + ex.Message);
        return 0;
    }

    mainForm.currentFileProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
    mainForm.currentFileProgressBar.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(streamIn.Length);
    mainForm.currentFileProgressBar.Value = 0;
    mainForm.Text = '[' + text + ']';

    BinaryReader inFile = new BinaryReader(streamIn);
    BinaryWriter outFile = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.Create));

    Trace.write("Out file name : " + ((FileStream)(outFile.BaseStream)).Name);

    const int BUFFER_LENGHT = 8388608;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LENGHT];

    int amountRead;

    const int CONVERSION = ((1024 * 1024) / 1000);

    Stopwatch stopwatchCompteurDatas = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatchCompteurDatas.Start();

    long currentFileAmountRead = 0;

    while ((amountRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LENGHT)) > 0)
    {
        outFile.Write(buffer, 0, amountRead);
        dataCounter += amountRead;
        currentFileAmountRead += amountRead;
        mainForm.currentFileProgressBar.Value += amountRead;
        mainForm.currentFileProgressBar.Invalidate();
        using (Graphics gr = mainForm.currentFileProgressBar.CreateGraphics())
        {
            gr.DrawString(Convert.ToString((100 * currentFileAmountRead) / streamIn.Length) + "% - " + inFileName, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(10, mainForm.currentFileProgressBar.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString("45" + "%", SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Height / 2.0F)));
        }

        if (dataCounter > (36870912))
        {
            elapsedTime += stopwatchCompteurDatas.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            stopwatchCompteurDatas.Restart();
            if (elapsedTime > 0)
            {
                double rate = dataCounter / (elapsedTime * CONVERSION);
                mainForm.Text = Convert.ToString(rate) + " Mb/s   [" + text + ']';
            }
            dataCounter = 0;
            elapsedTime = 0;
        }
    }

    inFile.Close();
    outFile.Close();

    return 0;
}
```

And some code from the form class :

```
// Drag'n drop Callback
void mainForm_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Extract the data from the DataObject-Container into a string list
    FileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);

     processFileList();
}


private async void processFileList()
{
    _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
    _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Maximum = FileList.Length-1;
    Trace.write("_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Maximum : " + _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Maximum);
    _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Value = 0;
    _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Step = 1;

    if ("" == _destinationFolderSelector.SelectedPath)
    {
        DialogResult result = this._destinationFolderSelector.ShowDialog();

        if(DialogResult.Cancel == result)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            _destinationFolderSelector.SelectedPath += '\\';
        }
    }

    Trace.write("destinationFolderSelector.SelectedPath : " + _destinationFolderSelector.SelectedPath);

    int filesCounter= 1;
    foreach (string File in FileList)
    {
        this.Text += File + "\n";

        var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        await Program.move(File, _destinationFolderSelector.SelectedPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File),
                (compteurFichiers++).ToString() + " / " + FileList.Length.ToString());

        //Program.move(File, _destinationFolderSelector.SelectedPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File), (compteurFichiers++).ToString() + " / " + FileList.Length.ToString());
        Trace.write(File);
        //++_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Value;
        _totalProcessFileProgressBar.PerformStep();
        Trace.write("_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Value : " + _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Value + " / " + _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Maximum);

        _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Hope you can help on this... on my side I read the doc about async, I don't get the way it works.

Comment: It appears you are running this foreach loop on the UI thread, is that correct? Also what version of .NET are you running, there are solutions that only became available in the later versions (like the `IProgress<T>` interface)

Comment: Or you could perform the IO operation on a worker thread.

Comment: I do a loop in the UI thread yes. Not used to program UI, so I guess I'm doing things wrongly. The thing is the upper progress bar acts just fine. I'm using .NET 4.5.

Comment: What does a worker thread looks like please ?

Comment: I'm also a little puzzled as in the video you provided everything seems just fine and dandy...
I also reproduced it and the only thing i could see if the little operation went by too fast the progress bar tends to not fill up before beginning the next operation (visually) but this obviously happens only on a multi threaded setting.

Comment: MrPaulch, sorry I'm not sure to get your point, what do you mean please ? I mean, about the multi threaded thing, anything I should change ?

Comment: I just noticed... have you attempted to set: `totalProcessFileProgressBar.Maximum = FileList.Length - 1;`

Comment: MrPaulch, I first added -1 as you said, but now thinking of it I think the right value is FileList.Length, not FileList.Length-1.
If I want to copy 8 files, 100% = 8 files copied, that mean the maximum value for the progressbar should be 8, not 7. Am I right ?

Comment: Only if you start your counter (`ProgressBar.Value`) at 1. But in your code you 'initialize' your counter at 0. So 7 would be the maximum with 8 files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Task.Run(...) for this. Seems like an invalidate/redraw related error since you are doing it all on the UI thread. Something like:

```
var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Program.move(File, _destinationFolder.SelectedPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File),
            (fileCounter++).ToString() + " / " + FileList.Length.ToString());
        Trace.write(File);
    }).ContinueWith((task) =>  ++_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Value, context);
```

Hope it helps nudge you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for you help. Seems like I can't do that this way. I tried to used a thread as well, and I get a System.InvalidOperationException, cause the progressbar a member of my form, and I'm accessing it from the thread. Seems I can't do that...

Comment: Could you tell me where you are calling the above snippet from? From a button click of destination? The "context" should ensure you are running it in the UI thread if you captured the context from the UI thread to begin with.

Comment: The snippet is part of a method that is called upon a drag'n drop. The drag'n drop is implemented in the form, it calls the Program.move(...) method. Program is the class containing the Main.

Comment: The destination button just opens a selection to choose the destination. The copy process begins when you drop some files somewhere else on the window, using the form drag'n drop callback.

Comment: The drag and drop callback should be executed on the UI thread. In which case the context would be proper. Just to make sure - you tried my code yeah? When I read your first comment again, you say "I tried to use a thread as well", just double-checking!

Comment: Yeas, I tried your code of course :)
The drag'n drop callback is executed in the UI thread, but it calles a method of the "main" class. The compiler doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that the code example in the question is not better. A more complete one would allow better answers. That said, I believe that all you really need here is to use the `async`/`await` pattern:

```
// Making the assumption here that the method is a button's Click event handler
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
    _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Maximum = FileList.Length;
    _totalProcessFileProgressBar.Value = 0;

    int fileCounter = 1;
    foreach (string File in FileList)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Program.move(File,
            _destinationFolder.SelectedPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File),
            (fileCounter++) + " / " + FileList.Length));
        Trace.write(File);
        ++_totalProcessFileProgressBar.Value;
    }
}
```

This causes each "move" operation to be processed in a worker thread while the UI thread continues. When each operation completes, execution returns, using the UI thread, to the statement immediately following the `await`, i.e. the `Trace.write(File);` method.

Depending on the actual implementation, it might be possible to make the `Program.move()` method an `async` method itself, allowing you to forgo the `Task.Run()` call and just `await` the `Program.move()` call directly. With the incomplete code example given, I can't offer more specific advice than that.

Note that the above assumes that `Trace.write(File);` is not a time-consuming operation. If it is, then it should be included in the worker thread's task instead of being after it. Alternatively, if the `Trace.write()` method requires access to some UI object, then you can turn that into an `async` method as well, using `Task` to execute the time-consuming part(s) in a worker thread but still accessing the UI object(s) in the UI thread. Again, with a more-complete code example, it would be possible to provide a more-complete answer here. Unfortunately, all I can do is try to address the most obvious possibilities, in a general way.

Comment: I made a reponse by modifying my original post, you can start reading at "The result is identical."

Comment: Sorry, the new code doesn't make sense. Your `Program.move()` method is declared as `async`, but it doesn't seem to do anything asynchronously. In fact, it doesn't have a single `await` statement; I don't see how it can even compile successfully. It looks as though you are trying to draw the progress information yourself, in the code doing the work, and that for sure is the wrong approach. In WinForms, you should only ever draw in response to a `Paint` event, i.e. either in a handler for that event or an `OnPaint()` method override (for customized controls).

Comment: No compilation problem, Visual just says that my asynchronous method is considered as synchronous. I can't use await statement since BinaryWriter&Reader don't have async version.
Moreover, at work we use Visual 2010, so I have to keep the code "2010 compliant". So I found a solution using a BackgroundWorker.
It works well with 2010, but I got an exception with 2013...
I should use the OnPaint technique you propose, but I don't know how to change my code.
I mean, my code is logical to me : I read 30% of the file, so I tell to progressBar : move to 30%. What else am I suppose to do ?

Comment: Ah, you don't have "warnings as errors" turned on. Okay. As far as the rest, the first step is to produce a usable code example. People need to be able to _easily_ compile and run the code you've shown, without having to add stuff to get it to work, and without being distracted/confused by extraneous elements of the code that aren't strictly related to the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You got me lost. First people said I posted too few code. So I added what I thought was useful. Now you threat me like idiot cause I posted too much.
So please, just STAY AWAY FROM MY POSTS.
I'll be pleased never to read of you again.

Comment: Sorry, you don't get to pick who reads and responds to your posts. That's not how SO works. Also, I'm not treating you like an idiot. I'm treating you like someone who has either not read, not understood, or not believed the guidance on how to create a correct code example. I have no doubt that the problem you are facing is solvable; the lack of an answer you find useful should be evidence enough that you haven't presented the question well enough for anyone to help you. Until you take that advice to heart, you will continue to have problems receiving the help you want.